# the given key was not present in the dictionary error debugging

Tags: c#, dictionary

When I debug the following code, it always throws the following exception:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

I need help figuring it out.

```cs
string current;
Dictionary<string, List<int>> map = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < y; i++){
    current = lines[i].material.Text + "," + lines[i].profilid.Text;
    if (map[current] == null){
        map[current] = new List<int>();
    }  
    map[current].Add(i);
    material_profile.Add(current);
 }

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> entry in map){
    List<int> lenghts = new List<int>();
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
    for (int i = 0; i < entry.Value.Count(); i++){
        int stueckzahl = int.Parse(lines[entry.Value[i]].stueck.Text);
        int laenge = int.Parse(lines[entry.Value[i]].länge.Text);

        for (int j = 0; j < stueckzahl; j++){
            lenghts.Add(laenge);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `map[current] == null` attempts to fetch the value from `map[current]`, and this will throw an error if there is no item.

If you wish to attempt to fetch an item which may not be present, you need to use the [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8) method.

This will work:

```
    List<int> list;
    if (!(map.TryGetValue(current, out list)))
    {
        list= new List<int>();
        map.Add(current, list);
    }
    list.Add(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Andrew Shepherd pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798928/336648), you can't look up a value that does not exist in a `Dictionary`.

For your test to make sense, you would have to expect `map[current]` to actually return the value `null`, but that would require the dictionary to actually contain a key-value pair where the key is the same value as `current`, and the value is `null`. In your case, that key does not exist at all.

The simplest solution to your problem may be to replace this line...

```
if (map[current] == null)
```

...with the following:

```
if (!map.ContainsKey(current))
```

That will search for the key without throwing an exception if it is not found.

---

*PS: You could also use `map.Add(current, new List<int>);` on the proceeding line instead of the `[]`-syntax - I personally think using `.Add(..)` makes the code a little simpler, but that may be a matter of preference.*